# PHP File Permissions inside Apache

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

I am creating a plugin-based PHP Application. For this application I have a config file which shall be readable only via the ConfigService.php.

The problem is that currently it would be possible for every plugin, to read the whole config file with database host, user, ...

Is there any possibility to restrict the file access via apache that only the service can read the config file?

SourcePath:

- config

  - app.config
- plugins

  - PluginA
  - PluginB
- web

  - Service

    - ConfigService.php
  - src

    - [sources]

My idea was something like defining open_basedir for the different directories.

- plugins may access plugins & web/Service
- Service may access Service & config
- Apache 

   with php_admin_value open_basedir "...plugins;...web/Service"

Or something like:

```
<Files ...config/app.config>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow From ...Service/ConfigService.php
</Files>
```

Does anyone has some ideas how to solve this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Apache won't help you in this. Apache detect if the exception of the url called is php, then send it to PHP, wich render it and give the whole response to Apache.

I don't think you can resolve it with chmod as your php script will be called by www-data, not depending on wich service it is.

When you say "plugins will have access to config", why is this a problem ? You will give access to the folder plugin to other développers and your don't want them to be able to read the config ?

Comment: File permissions don't work on a "which file can access which file" basis. It's always which ***user*** can access which files. Since the PHP process is running as one particular user, either all of PHP has access to a file or none of it. You'd have to spawn a separate PHP process using a different user if you want to use the file permission system.

Comment: Thank you so far, seems to be tricky.

Yes, I want my Service to be called to get config data because passwords are protected and not available through the service but if every plugin can read the config file, it is possible to read the passwords...

Encryption may also not be a solution because the password or the private key must be read by the plugin manager and would also be readable for the plugins. 

Is there no chance to protect the config file from being outside a directory? The open_basedir config seemed to be a solution if I could configure it for every single directory...

Comment: In short: you want to run code which you don't trust. That's… tricky at best. There are a ton of things code you don't trust may do which you don't like. Maybe it's best to examine that fundamental distrust.